# Решение уравнения с тремя неизвестными

Tags: математика

Есть уравнение вида:

x+256y+256²z=3289392

Необходимо найти x, y, z. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Применить к уравнению сравнение по модулю *256* и посмотреть что получится.

Comment: И записать уравнение как-то понятнее, с правильным форматированием или вовсе без него, но чтоб оно однозначно читалось...

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать пример, так как я не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать?

Comment: Я бы показал, но я не понимаю, каким оно должно быть...

Comment: Если вы понимаете что такое "сравнение по модулю *256*", то вы уже решили задачу. Если нет, почитайте википедию или учебник.

Comment: прошу прощения, вот правильное уравнение:
x+256y+256*256z=a
a=3289392

Comment: Ну а про остаток от деления вы слышали?

Comment: x+256y+256²z = 50\*256²+49\*256+48. Если на x,y,z не наложены дополнительные условия, то решений, вообще говоря, бесконечно много даже в целых числах, и просто много в натуральных. Или я что-то недопонял? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Могу добавить, что x, y, z < 256 @Harry

Comment: Ну ни фига себе, самое главное и не сказано. Послушайте, задачи так не задают! Ответ на ваше задачу — которую вы изначально задали — "выбрать произвольные y и z, и найти x = 3289392 - 256y-256²z"...

Comment: Кстати, ваше условие "x, y, z < 256" не мешает получить, например, решение z=100, y=100, x=-3264564.  Без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Comment: @Harry, не придирайтесь. Без ограничений на модуль и диофантовость задача имеет мало смысла. Понятно что ТС учат переводу в систему счисления.

Comment: По-видимому, задача должна формулироваться так: записать число 3289392 в 256-ричной системе счисления.

Comment: @rotabor, задача всё в то чтобы ТС понял как такие вещи делаются.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Это не придирки, а вопрос как минимум уважения к тем, кто хочет тебе помочь (и, кстати, соответственно, самоуважения :)). С моей точки зрения это существенно некорректное поведение.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var ba = BitConverter.GetBytes(3289392);
Console.WriteLine($"x {ba[0]} y {ba[1]} z {ba[2]}");
-->
x 48 y 49 z 50
```

О как

Comment: Не хватает пояснений этого трюка )